# SQL Joining two tables, both have one column that's exactly the same

Tags: python, sql, join, select

I'm trying to create a new table out of these two tables down below. I want my new table to have the columns Sport, Avg_age, and Avg_age_with_medal. How to do that in SQL?

Table 1 Python/SQL Code:

```
pysqldf("SELECT Sport, AVG(Age) AS Avg_age \
     FROM athlete_events \
     GROUP BY Sport \
     ;")
```

[image]

Table 2 Python/SQL Code:

```
pysqldf("SELECT Sport, AVG(Age) AS Avg_age_with_medal \
     FROM athlete_events \
     WHERE Medal IN ('Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze') \
     GROUP BY Sport")
```

[image]

Comment: you can combine two SQL statements with UNION or UNION ALL keyword. if you want a particular order to the results, you do that only once at the very end. the SQL parsers i've used wouldn't permit ordering the two intermediary parts separately.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] PS Do you mean `create` a table or write a query or a view? What are the exact inputs (expressions?) & goal/deliverable? Please show relevant parts you can do & explain about being stuck referencing your research results. [ask] [Help] PS [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding in both of your queries you are using the same table to calculate the Avg_age and Avg_age_with_medal. In this case you could try something like this.

```
SELECT Sport, 
       AVG(age) AS avg_age,
       AVG(CASE WHEN medal in ('Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze') 
           THEN age ELSE null
           end)as avg_age_with_medal
FROM athlete_events
GROUP BY Sport
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73b5560af4e50376f7a04c9e669f6c30)